# Run a command in loop until timeout, then export variable

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to run a command in bash until it succeeds, but limit it with a timeout. The problem here is that I am using a subshell, therefore the main shell is unable to get the correct value:

```
timeout 10m bash -c 'until vm_ip=$( openstack server show f530d850-e255-4c5e-b984-43c4143a751b -c addresses --format value | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" ); do sleep 30; done'
```

With this I am trying to get the IP of a VM until it reaches a timeout. I would like to be able to use `vm_ip` after this command.

Comment: Can't you just omit the `bash -c` and the quotes in the command?

Comment: @myradio `until` is a built-in, it won't work like that

Comment: Yes, you are right. Of course a dirty work around is to write to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it`s sufficient to just print the result to `stdout` and capture it to the variable in the target shell:

```sh
vm_ip="$( timeout 10m bash -c 'until vm_ip_internal=$( openstack server show f530d850-e255-4c5e-b984-43c4143a751b -c addresses --format value | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" ); do sleep 30; done; echo "$vm_ip_internal"' )"
echo "$vm_ip"
```